# Flutter TextField/TextFormField does not update its value on setState()

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have the following component on my flutter page.

```
TextFormField(
                    controller: surveyDateController, 
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Survey Date',
                    ),
                  ),
```

And i have the following controller for the above control

```
  final surveyDateController = TextEditingController();
```

The data is coming from _data.leadSurvey[0].title which is loaded from an API. Once the data is loaded I am calling the setState method as follows:

```
setState(() {
        _data = data;
      });
```

But the data in the TextFormField is not getting updated. Tried using the initialValue property but it generates a null error.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 1):

Set data to the controller in the setState()

```
  setState(() {
        _data = data;
        surveyDateController.text = _data.leadSurvey[0].title
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure where `data` should appear, but if you want it to appear in your `TextFormField`, I guess you have to call `surveyDateController.value = data`

Comment: Since there are around 20 TextFormFields in my page, is it recommended to set the value for every TextFormField using the controller?

<controllername>.value=<value>

Comment: When I try to do that I am getting an error as following: A value of type String can not be assigned to a variable of TextEditingValue

Comment: @iShah I am not completely sure what your goal is. Normally a `TextFormField` is for inputting Text and not displaying it. Also, do you have just one `TextEditingController` for all of your Fields?

Comment: @iShah Oh, yeah, its like @Jhoan said `surveyDateController.text`. I had the native Android in my head.

Comment: What i am trying to do is to retrieve the data from the server (using API) and allowing the user to edit it and send it back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

after you get the data String from the server

then set your editing controller (surverDateController)

```
surveyDateController.text = _data.leadSurvey[0].title
```

Comment: It works fine.. the only issue here is I have to keep doing this manually everytime the data is changed..

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have $your_text_controller$ and have assigned it to your text field as follow:

```
TextFormField(
                    controller: surveyDateController, 
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Survey Date',
                    ),
                  ),
```

now, you can set the text of this text field by calling this function everywhere you want:

```
void setText(){

    setState((){
        surveyDateController.text = "Your Text"; // Ex. _data.leadSurvey[0].title
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the TextFormField a default value:

```
final surveyDateController = TextEditingController(text: 'initial data here');
```

To re-assign the TextFormField a value:

```
surveyDateController.text = _data;
```